# Is recycling introducing toxins into products that come in contact with food?

Tags: toxicity

Paper products like napkins and paper plates made from recycled material might have unsafe levels of toxins if the original recycled materials contain toxic inks, etc. How big of a health concern is this?

EDIT: Not sure how this is too broad -- my goal is to start a discussion about a problem that I have not heard mentioned before.

Comment: Surprised but such products do exist. http://letsgogreen.biz/pages/paper.html

Comment: All toilet paper is made at least partially from recycled material.

Answer (score 1):

None, if you can trust your producer, and the safety agency controlling him.

The problem is more the large water and bleach consumption of the recycling factory, that makes sure your new recycled toilet paper is safe, and the environmentally safe waste disposal of said factory.

Comment: I am not convinced that if toxins start out in the original paper that it can be effectively removed at least in an economical way. So part of the question is, how toxic are, for example, the inks and dyes in a colorful laundry detergent box? At one time, I am pretty sure such a box would have had a lot of lead; at one time the labels on Wonder Bread were printed with lead ink.

Comment: @Jeff  Such inks have long been forbidden in the more civilised parts of the world.

Comment: I hope so. Are you familiar with the Wonder Bread incident? A label printed inside-out so bread was in direct contact with ink caused acute lead poisoning in kids. BTW perhaps recycled paper may not come from "civilized" parts of the world.

Comment: @Jeff Well, that's true. Plastic toys with toxic paint etc. regularly make it into our newspapers. Horray for globalised production without retraceble quality control.